# jQuery accessing previous element value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in my cshtml Razor page:

```
 @foreach (var localRecord in Model.electionData)
 {
      <div class="row">
           <label for="@localRecord.ElementID" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label text-left">@localRecord.FundName</label>
           <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control election" id="@localRecord.ElementID" min="@localRecord.MinPct" max="@localRecord.MaxPct" value="0">
                <input type="number" hidden value="@localRecord.HostFID" />
           </div>
      </div>
 }
```

And I have the following jQuery code which executes when the user clicks on a submit button:

```
 var sendData = [];
 var fundName = "";
 var percent = 0;
 var fund = 0;
 var data = {};

 $('.election').each(function () {
       percent = parseInt($(this).val());
       if (percent > 0) {
           fund = $(this).next().val();
           fundName = $(this).prev().prev().val();
           console.log("fundName = " + fundName);
           data = {
               'fund': fund,
               'fundName': fundName,
               'percent': percent
           };
           sendData.push(data);
       }
   });
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "@Url.Action("Summary")",
       dataType: "text",
       data: { 'formData': sendData },
       success: function (msg) {
           $("form").attr('action', '/OnlineEnrollment/Summary');
           $("form").submit();
       },
       error: function (req, status, error) {
           console.log("in ajax error function");
           console.log(req);
           console.log(status);
           console.log(error);
           console.log(msg);
       }
   });
```

When the code runs, I am able to pick up the percent value from $(this).val() and I am able to pick up the fund value from $(this).next().val().  I have been unable to pick up the fund name value.  I have tried $(this).prev().val() and $(this).prev().prev().val().  Both give me undefined.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fund name is not previous to the `.election` object. It's previous to the *parent* of the `.election` object.

Also, the element with the fund name is not an input field, so it doesn't have a value. It's a `<label>`, so use `.text()` to get its contents.

So use

```
fundName = $(this).parent().prev().text();
```